# receiving response from json webservice using unknown key

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am receiving response from json web service and able to parse it.
But when I am parsing the json data using [mydic allKeys] (as unknown keys will be parse using allKeys method) it gives me response but it changes the order of receiving keys.

So I want the order should not be changed. If anybody knows the solution please help.

Thanks.

Comment: Dictionaries are not-ordered data structures so array created by`allKeys` can be different.

Comment: So how to solve this problem?

Comment: You need to *manually* pick values from dictionary by keys and put them to array.

Comment: But I am receiving values from unknown keys.That is the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known behavior. The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdictionary/1409150-allkeys) states:

> **allKeys Property**
>
> A new array containing the dictionary’s keys, or an empty array if the
>   dictionary has no entries
>
> **The order of the elements in the array is not defined.**

Comment: thank you for help the documentation helped me..